# Bean created using @Bean is not autowired when @RestController bean already exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

Foo.java

```
        @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/foo")
        public class Foo{

        @Autowired
        Bar bar;

        @RequestMapping("/beanTest")
        public void beanTest() {
            System.out.println("Foo's Bar is "+bar);
        }   
        }
```

---

Bar.java

```
  @RestController
  class Bar{ }
```

---

Config.java

```
   @Configuration

   public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Bar getBar() {

        Bar bar=new Bar();
        System.out.println("@Bean Bar is "+bar);
        return bar;

    }
}
```

---

Problem :
     Problem is we have 2 Bar beans 1 created for @RestController and other created by @Bean.
     Now when we autowire the Bar using @Autowired annotation then bean created by @Bean is not
     getting injected and other one is picked up why ?
     According to me as there are 2 beans registered with application context here for the same type Bar
     application should have failed because it should not be able to decide which one to inject.

```
OUTPUT :

@Bean Bar is com.example.practiceBoot.controller.Bar@56e07a08

Foo's Bar is com.example.practiceBoot.controller.Bar@6ae18a78
```

Comment: `@RestController` is meta-annotated with `@Controller` which means that a bean is automatically created, remove the `@RestController` annotation. Also, your `Bar` bean should be defined in your `@Configuration` class, not in your controller.

Comment: I agree that Bean annotation should be inside the Config class somewhere else but the point is if we remove the RestController from Bar then bean created with Bean annotation gets injected. So why Restcontroller's bean gets the preference.

Comment: If you want to have more than one beans for the same class you should give them a name. Otherwise, when the second instance is initialized Spring overwrites the first one. I don't think there is a way to predict the order Spring loads beans. If you need a specific order you can use annotations like Order or DependOn.

Comment: It depends how things are loaded and you haven't shown how things are loaded so it is actually impossible to answer.